# How to list Excel Slicer Items in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have Win10 and Excel 2016.  This is is really perplexing to me.  I have a number of Slicers in an Excel workbook file.  In my test code, all I wanted to do are (1) Get a count of the Slicer items in the Slicer, but I got a

> Run-time error '1004' Application-defined or object-defined error:

```
Debug.Print ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_BusinessDivision").SlicerItems.count
```

(2) I want to list out all the Slicer items using the below code, in this case also got the '1004' error:

```
Dim oSlicerItem       As slicerItem
      
For Each oSlicerItem In ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_BusinessDivision").SlicerItems
    Debug.Print oSlicerItem.Value
Next
```

According to the MS documentation, `SlicerItems` property is contained in a `SlicerCache` object in:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.sliceritems

which is what I specified and also Intellisense showed it as well. Interesting, when I `Dim` the object variable as above, Excel turn `As SlicerItem` to the lower case `As slicerItem`.  Can you share your thoughts.  I have been looking at the MS documentation and I don't know what I am doing wrong.

From:   `Dim oSlicerItem       As SlicerItem`

To:     `Dim oSlicerItem       As slicerItem`

After making adjustment based on BigBen and Tim's comment, I looked at the documentation, which said:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.slicercachelevel

"Use the **SlicerCacheLevels** collection of the parent **SlicerCache** object to access the **SlicerCacheLevel** objects that represent these hierarchy levels."

**Properties**

- Application
- Count
- Creator
- CrossFilterType
- Name
- Ordinal
- Parent
- **SlicerItems**
- SortItems
- VisibleSlicerItemsList

which contains the SlicerItems collection, but not sure how I can access this.  I tried using:

```
Dim cache             As SlicerCache

Set cache = ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_BusinessDivision")
Debug.Print cache.OLAP = True  '//this is true
   
Debug.Print cache.SlicerCacheLevels.Parent
```

But Intellisense does not show anything else beyond ".Parent", any ideas?

Thanks in advance,

G.

Comment: Try splitting that into steps: i.e. `DIm cache As SlicerCache`, `Set cache = ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_BusinessDivision")`. If that succeeds, then the issue is with `SlicerItems`.

Comment: Ben, I am still getting it the '1004' error at the FOR EACH line.     Dim cache             As SlicerCache
   
  
   Set cache = ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_BusinessDivision")
   For Each oSlicerItem In cache.SlicerItems
      Debug.Print oSlicerItem.Value
      
   Next

Comment: Is your data from an OLAP data connection, or not?

Comment: "Attempting to access the SlicerItems property for slicers that are connected to an external OLAP data source (SlicerCache.OLAP = True) generates a run-time error. For OLAP data sources, use the SlicerItems property of the SlicerCacheLevel object instead."

Comment: Edit your post to add the updated code, its too hard to read in the comments

Answer (score 0):

I want to thank you both, Ben and Tim, for pointing me in the right direction regarding OLAP.  I totally forgot that it was point to it. Additionally, I like to share my code snippet that worked:

```
Sub test()

   Dim oSlicerItem       As SlicerItem
   Dim cache             As SlicerCache


   Set cache = ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_BusinessDivision")
   Debug.Print cache.OLAP   '//True
    
    
   Debug.Print cache.SlicerCacheLevels(1).SlicerItems.Count
   For Each oSlicerItem In cache.SlicerCacheLevels(1).SlicerItems
      Debug.Print oSlicerItem.Value
   Next

End Sub
```

I had to use the index 1 because there's only one level and lo and behold, it cycled through all the items in the Slicer.  Thank you again.

G